# How to install Gnome Terminal 3.32 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, snap, flatpak

Can I install Gnome Terminal 3.32 in Ubuntu 18.04 using flatpak, snap, or something?

I already use Gnome Games 3.32 as flatpak, but couldn't find Gnome Terminal 3.32.

Answer (score 3):

GNOME terminal is available neither as snap package or flatpak. GNOME terminal 3.32 is packed in 19.04 (Disco Dingo). While it can be installed via APT using either of the two methods listed below but I'll suggest you to upgrade to 19.04 if you really want to use GNOME terminal 3.32. It'll be better under GNOME 3.32 (in 19.04) instead of GNOME 3.28 (in 18.04).

1. **Typical method**: This method simply includes downloading debs from [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) for 19.04 (Disco) and installing them using dpkg.

   - Download necessary packages:

     ```
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal_3.32.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-data_3.32.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte2.91/libvte-2.91-0_0.56.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte2.91/libvte-2.91-common_0.56.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls30_3.6.5-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nettle/libhogweed4_3.4.1-1_amd64.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle6_3.4.1-1_amd64.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre2/libpcre2-8-0_10.32-5_amd64.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/p11-kit/p11-kit-modules_0.23.15-2_amd64.deb
     wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/p11-kit/libp11-kit0_0.23.15-2_amd64.deb
     ```
   - Install using dpkg:

     ```
     sudo dpkg -i gnome-terminal_3.32.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
     gnome-terminal-data_3.32.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb libvte-2.91-0_0.56.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
     libvte-2.91-common_0.56.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb libgnutls30_3.6.5-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
     libhogweed4_3.4.1-1_amd64.deb libnettle6_3.4.1-1_amd64.deb \
     libpcre2-8-0_10.32-5_amd64.deb p11-kit-modules_0.23.15-2_amd64.deb \
     libp11-kit0_0.23.15-2_amd64.deb
     ```
   - Install any dependency if left:

     ```
     sudo apt install -f
     ```
2. **Dirty method**: This method can be used if you are too lazy to solve dependency issues of GNOME terminal by yourself and want APT to do that for you.

   - Add Disco's main repository to sources.list.

     ```
     echo -e "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
     ```
   - Update and install GNOME terminal

     ```
     sudo apt update
     sudo apt install --no-install-recommends gnome-terminal -f
     ```
   - Remove Disco's main repository.

     ```
     sudo sed -i '$ d' /etc/apt/sources.list
     ```

   The main repository for Disco should be removed immediately after installation since if you try to upgrade your system, it might break your system horribly.

After upgrading GNOME terminal,*"Open in terminal"* option in nautilus will be lost due to dependency issues of **nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal**  unless nautilus is also upgraded to 3.32. Remove that extension too if you want to stick to that Nautilus version.

```
sudo apt autoremove nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
```

Comment: I love the dirty method! :D

Comment: How to revert back the gnome-terminal upgraded using the dirty method? 

(I used "eoan" instead of "disco" since that didn't find a release file)

Comment: @Hrishikesh Disco's repository must have provided 3.34. Did you check the packages being updated? Just remove them and eoan's repository. Reinstall those packages.

Comment: @Kulfy I tried that already, (removing eoan repository and then installing gnome-terminal again, but it said it is already installed.) I didn't dare remove gnome-terminal from the fear of breaking the system

Answer (score 0):

I think the first way is really messy too.
It will result in number of broken references in your packages database, ie apt database, easily getting you to the point where you need to reinstall you system.